# Calling private functions with NSTimer?

Tags: swift, nstimer, private

Is there a way to have an `NSTimer` call a `private func` when the timeout has expired?

(Does this even make sense? The NSTimer reference is local to the class, I'm not sure the caller's target at runtime is local, as well.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you just need to mark the function `@objc`:

```
 @objc private func runner(timer: NSTimer) {
```

Then it will respond to the selector, but be private to Swift.